# 'variable' is local and global Python

Tags: python

I've been getting an error with a function that is supposed to change a global variable to keep a counter. It's for a game, in this case it would be 'playerHealth' and 'strength'. How can I fix this error?

```
strength = 1
playerHealth = 100

def orcCombat(playerHealth, playerDamage, strength):
    orcHealth = 60
    while orcHealth > 0:
        if playerHealth > 10:
            print "You swing your sword at the orc!, He loses", playerDamage, "health!"
            playerHealth = playerHealth - 10
            orcHealth = orcHealth - playerDamage
        elif playerHealth == 10:
            print "The Orc swings a deadly fist and kills you!"
            print "Game Over"
        else:
            print "The Orc has killed you"
            print "Game Over"
            sys.exit()

    if orcHealth <= 0:
        print "You killed the Orc!"
        print "+1 Strength"
        global strength
        strength = strength + 1
    return "press enter to continue"
```

error: **name 'strength' is global and local.

Here's the new code. The strength error is fixed, but the global variable playerHealth is not changed, and if I declare playerHealth as a global variable it gives me the error again.

```
import sys

charisma = 1
strength = 1
intelligence = 1
agility = 1
courage = 1
playerDamage = 20
magic = 0
playerHealth = 100

def orcCombat(playerHealth, playerDamage):


    orcHealth = 60

    while orcHealth > 0:
        if playerHealth > 10:
            print "You swing your sword at the orc!, He loses", playerDamage, "health!"
            playerHealth = playerHealth - 10
            orcHealth = orcHealth - playerDamage
        elif playerHealth == 10:
            print "The Orc swings a deadly fist and kills you!"
            print "Game Over"
        else:
            print "The Orc has killed you"
            print "Game Over"
            sys.exit()


    if orcHealth <= 0:
        print "You killed the Orc!"
        print "+1 Strength"
        print "HP = ", playerHealth
        global strength 
        strength = strength + 1
    return "press enter to continue"

orcCombat(playerHealth, playerDamage)
print strength
print playerHealth
```

How do I change the function so it changes the global variable playerHealth? 
Thanks

Comment: Your indentation looks a little funky. Is `orcHealth = 60`  supposed to have the same amount of spacing as `def orcCombat`? That means it's outside the function.

Comment: Oops, gotta fix that. Thanks for noticing

Comment: I think you still have some indentation issues, the code starting at `orcHealth = 60` should be 4 spaces indented if it is the body of the "orcCombat" function.

Comment: Thats an error when I pasted the code into the question, the actual code is indented properly.

Comment: `strength` is always intended to be a global, whether or not the code that updates it is reached or not. Move `global strength` to the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because of a naming conflict between the `strength` parameter of the function and the global variables `strength`. Either rename the function parameter or remove it entirely.

Comment: You have helped me a lot. I have learned a lot from this. I am thankful

Answer (score 2):

```
def orcCombat(playerHealth, playerDamage, strength):
```

You don't need to pass global variables as arguments to your function. Try:

```
def orcCombat(playerHealth, playerDamage):
```

Comment: It works when I isolate the function. Thanks for the advice, let me see if it works together as a whole.

Comment: This worked well to fix one of my problems. I edited the original question to the new problem.

Comment: If you want playerHealth to be global too, then delete that from the `def` line too.

Answer (score 2):

when you pass the variable 'strength' or in this case `foo` to a function, the function creates local scope in which `foo` refers to the variable passed in the context of the function `test1`.

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> def test1(foo):
...   foo = foo + 1
...   return
...
>>> test1(foo)
>>> foo
1
```

As you can see, the 'global' foo has not changed. In this second version we use the `global` keyword.

```
>>> def test2():
...   global foo
...   foo = foo + 1
...   return
...
>>> foo
1
>>> test2()
>>> foo
2
```

have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Another option is to pass the the variable `foo` to the function as you have, when you return from the function you just return the variable `foo`
along with any other variables using a tuple.

Comment: The problem is that when I pass playerHealth or strength as a global variable, it gives me the error 'name is local and global'

Comment: Are you declaring it global inside the function?

Comment: Just use global once at the beginning of the function.